# Add '/' in front of every character of a string (and after the last one)

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

How can we use `sed` or `awk` to translate `unix` to `/u/n/i/x/`.
I was able to do this with Python as follows:

```
separator='/'
separator.join(string)+separator
```

But how can we achieve this in Shell?

Comment: What should the output be if the input is an empty string, e.g. `echo "" | whatever`? Should the output be `//` or `/` or an empty string again or something else?

Comment: FWIW, your python code will turn `unix` into `u/n/i/x/`, not `/u/n/i/x/`.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ echo unix | sed -e 's,.,&/,g' -e 's,^,/,'
/u/n/i/x/
```

This is similar to [NiteRain's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608902/116858), but removes a `sed` invocation by letting a single `sed` execute two expression, and simplifies the regular expression used by using commas as an alternative delimiter for the `s///` command.

The first substitution used here replaces each and every character in the input string with itself followed by a `/` character.  The second substitution inserts a `/` at the start of the string.

The `sed` command could be shortened to `sed 's,.,&/,g; s,^,/,'`, i.e. using a single argument containing both substitutions separated by a `;`.

---

Using GNU `sed`, you could also do

```
$ echo unix | sed 's,.\{0\},/,g'
/u/n/i/x/
```

The `.\{0\}` matches exactly zero characters.  GNU `sed` makes this expression match in-between each character in the string.  Other `sed` implementation may treat this as an error.  Here, OpenBSD `sed`:

```
$ echo unix | sed 's,.\{0\},/,g'
sed: 1: "s,.\{0\},/,g": RE error: empty (sub)expression
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about `.\{0\}`... `perl` supports it with empty expression `echo unix | perl -lpe 's||/|g'`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "unix" | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\/\1/g' | sed -e 's/$/\//'
```

output:

```
/u/n/i/x/
```

Comment: Thank you, "/u/n/i/x" output I get, How can I make it "/u/n/i/x/"
Do you any good resources so I can learn SED?

Comment: you would use another sed targeting the end of the string.  As for something that can help learn SED, this seems like a good [link](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: `s` allows you to choose a delimiter in its syntax. Since the OP wants to add `/`, choosing `/` and then having to escape some instances of it seems the less readable choice. The last expression with another character chosen looks so much clearer: `s:$:/:`. The same applies to the first `sed` expression.

Comment: Thanks Guys..it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way with sed is that we stick a newline at the end.

```
$ echo Unix | sed -n 'G;s|.|/&|g;P'
/U/n/i/x/
```

The below methods can also be used. Both use the GNU versions of awk n sed.

```
$ echo Unix | sed -e 's/./\n&/g;G' | paste -sd'/'
```

```
$ echo Unix | awk '{$1=OFS $1}++NF' FPAT=. OFS=/
```

The best resource for the sed editor is the O'Reillys' sed n awk by Dale Dougherty, et.al. Plus hang around sed groups like this one n learn from other's approaches which will bring you up to speed quicker.

Answer (score 0):

With any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ echo 'unix' | awk '{gsub(/./,"/&"); print $0"/"}'
/u/n/i/x/
```

Comment: UNIX is a brand trademarked by TOG, Unix is an operating system.

Comment: Fair enough, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

**using Raku (formerly known as Perl 6)**

```
~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g/(.)/{"/"}{$0}/;'
/u/n/i/x
```

There are concerns as to what happens when you feed in a blank string (thanks @Ed Morton). Using the above code, if you feed a blank string to Raku you get a blank return:

```
~$ echo "" | raku -pe 's:g/(.)/{"/"}{$0}/;'

~$
```

Perlish languages are famous for TMTOWTDI, so here are a few variations in case any strike your fancy. [note, the `s///` operator can accept other separators like `^`, `!`, `?`, etc.]:

```
~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g/(.)/\/$0/;'
/u/n/i/x
~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g/(.)/\/{$0}/;'
/u/n/i/x

~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g^(.)^/$0^;'
/u/n/i/x
~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g^(.)^/{$0}^;'
/u/n/i/x
~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g^(.)^{"/"}{$0}^;'
/u/n/i/x

~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g!(.)!/$0!;'
/u/n/i/x
~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g!(.)!/{$0}!;'
/u/n/i/x
~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g!(.)!{"/"}{$0}!;'
/u/n/i/x

~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g?(.)?/$0?;'
/u/n/i/x
~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g?(.)?/{$0}?;'
/u/n/i/x
~$ echo "unix" | raku -pe 's:g?(.)?{"/"}{$0}?;'
/u/n/i/x
```

HTH.

https://raku.org/

Answer (score -1):

```
 echo "unix"| sed "s/./&\//g"
u/n/i/x/
```

Answer (score -2):

Some GNU `gawk` solutions:

```
$ echo "unix" | awk -v FS='' -v OFS='/' 'BEGIN { printf "/"}; $1=$1 { printf $0 }; END { print "/" } ' 
/u/n/i/x/
$
```

Here is another shorter script which handles leading zeros and does not use `printf`:

```
$ echo "0unix" | awk -F '' -v OFS='/' '{$1=$1}1 { print "/"$0"/" }'
/0/u/n/i/x/
$
```

Another solution:

```
$ echo "0unix" | awk -v FPAT='.' -v OFS='/' '{$1=$1}1 { print "/"$0"/" }'
/0/u/n/i/x/
$
```

These scripts may or may not work with other implementations of the AWK language.  In particular, the special meaning of setting `FS` to an empty string, will result in a warning message in some versions of `awk` such as `nawk`. Note that `FPAT` is specific to `gawk`.

Comment: Never do `printf $0`, always use `printf "%s", $0` instead (for any input data). The former will fail cryptically when the input contains `printf` formatting characters like `%s`.

Comment: @EdMorton True, but it does not fail in this particular use case!

Comment: You're probably right and that's just a bad habit which won't bite you in this particular case since you're processing single chars. There are 2 other failure points in the script though: 1) setting FS to null is undefined behavior per POSIX so in some awks it'll split the input into chars as you want while on others it won't, and 2) Testing for the result of `$1=$1` would fail when the first character is `0`.

Comment: @EdMorton. Stating that there "are 2 other failure points" is factually incorrect and misleading .  Stating that there are 2 other potential failure points would have been more accurate. First, the OP did not state any POSIX or portability requirements. If the OP had, the requirements would have been met.  Second, the first character of the sample string supplied by the OP is not `0`. If a leading zero requirement had been specified by the OP, my answer would have taken that into account.